# Reset Stats on Admin Dashboard

Tags: admin, dashboard

How can I reset to zero the dashboard stats without deleting orders.

```
truncate table sales_flat_order;
```

truncate table sales_order_tax;
truncate table downloadable_link_purchased;

delete from eav_entity_store WHERE entity_type_id in (
select entity_type_id FROM eav_entity_type WHERE entity_type_code in ('order', 'invoice', 'creditmemo', 'shipment')
);

[image]
Thank you,
Elvis

Comment: please refer the below mention site. https://gist.github.com/mystix/5360885. In this very useful for reset Magento admin Dashboard data(like Last 5 Search Terms, Top 5 Search Terms)

Comment: Thank you @Sankar_k How can I reset Lifetime Sales and Average Orders without deleting orders?